# Error installing keystone.js

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I tried to install keystone.js on AWS ( Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS instance).

At root ran :

```
sudo npm install -g generator-keystone
```

at "var/node2/finweb" ran:

```
sudo  yo keystone
```

Got the following error:

```
undefined:76
 } if (userModelPath.includes('-')) { ;
                 ^
TypeError: Object users has no method 'includes'
    at eval (eval at template (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone   node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:6306:22),   <anonymous>:76:22)
    at KeystoneGenerator.underscore [as _engine] (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/engines.js:31:45)
at KeystoneGenerator.engine (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:314:10)
at KeystoneGenerator.template (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:289:15)
at KeystoneGenerator.project (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/app/index.js:320:7)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:395:14
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
```

Any ideas? It must be something basic, as I haven't done very much. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Node do you have installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, while trying to fix things I ended up locking myself out of my AWS instance, now I get "permission denied", which is a separate problem. Once I solve that I will try to reply to your inquiry concerning my Node version. Hopefully soon.